# How to measure peak heap memory usage in Java?

Tags: java, heap-memory

How to measure peak heap memory usage in Java? MemoryPoolMXBean keeps track of the peak usage per memory pool, but not the entire heap. And the peak heap usage is not simply the sum of different heap memory pools.

Answer (score 3):

Did you think about using `totalMemory()` function from `Runtime` class - [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)?
Also there are some free tools like [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) or [JStat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html), example:

```
jstat -gc <pid> <time> <amount>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm interested in measuring the peak memory usage occurred when running a particular piece of code. It looks like totalMemory() doesn't return this information.

Comment: it's extremely hard to measure memory usage of particular piece of code. You can google it, but perfect approach is not available (currently).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the peak heap size, you can combine the **peak used size** of all the memory pools which are of **type HEAP**.

Here is an example:

```
List<MemoryPoolMXBean> pools = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
long total = 0;
for (MemoryPoolMXBean memoryPoolMXBean : pools)
{
  if (memoryPoolMXBean.getType() == MemoryType.HEAP)
  {
    long peakUsed = memoryPoolMXBean.getPeakUsage().getUsed();
    System.out.println("Peak used for: " + memoryPoolMXBean.getName() + " is: " + peakUsed);
    total = total + peakUsed;
  }
}

System.out.println("Total heap peak used: " + Util.format(total));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article https://cruftex.net/2017/03/28/The-6-Memory-Metrics-You-Should-Track-in-Your-Java-Benchmarks.html, it mentions `GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo` and there is [implementation using JMH](https://github.com/cache2k/cache2k-benchmark/blob/master/jmh-suite/src/main/java/org/cache2k/benchmark/jmh/GcProfiler.java) (I haven't tried it yet)